# Extracting an item from a list of lists?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm doing a lisp related assignment for class and one of the problems requires us to use `mapcar` to "extract" an item from a list (whether that means that he wants us to print it, or simply remove it, I don't know entirely, I'm assuming that he would like us to print it.)

I generally understanding using something like `(nth 3 (list 1 2 3 4))` to get the third item from the list, but using `mapcar` makes this seem overly complicated - especially when the data he wants us to test is (he wants us to extract the social security numbers):

```
((olsen jimmy 123-76-4535 cub-reporter)
 (kent clark 089-52-6787 reporter)
 (lane lois 951-26-1438 reporter)
 (white perry 355-16-7439 editor))
```

Could someone guide me on how exactly to do this using `mapcar`? I've been looking up weblinks on it, and seems like `mapcar` is generally used to do something specific to EACH item in a list, not a single item. (Or maybe I'm understanding the problem wrong?)

Comment: "I generally understanding using something like (nth 3 (list 1 2 3 4)) to get the third item" -- I hope it returns the fourth in your lisp. nth begins at 0, so  (nth 0 '(1 2 3 4)) would return 1.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to figure it out - it was surprisingly simple, all you really needed was to do "third" on the list of items.  My resulting code was:

```
(setf daily-planet
    '((olsen jimmy 123-76-4535 cub-reporter)
      (kent clark 089-52-6787 reporter)
      (lane lois 951-26-1438 reporter)
      (white perry 355-16-7439 editor)))

(mapcar #'third daily-planet)
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
CL-USER 26 > (setf daily-planet
                   '((olsen jimmy 123-76-4535 cub-reporter)
                     (kent clark 089-52-6787 reporter)
                     (lane lois 951-26-1438 reporter)
                     (white perry 355-16-7439 editor)))

((OLSEN JIMMY |123-76-4535| CUB-REPORTER) (KENT CLARK |089-52-6787| REPORTER)
 (LANE LOIS |951-26-1438| REPORTER) (WHITE PERRY |355-16-7439| EDITOR))
```

Your solution:

```
CL-USER 27 > (mapcar #'third daily-planet)

(|123-76-4535| |089-52-6787| |951-26-1438| |355-16-7439|)
```

**Exploring the alternatives**

Just using a lambda function doing nothing. It only returns each item:

```
CL-USER 28 > (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                         x)
                     daily-planet)

((OLSEN JIMMY |123-76-4535| CUB-REPORTER) (KENT CLARK |089-52-6787| REPORTER)
 (LANE LOIS |951-26-1438| REPORTER) (WHITE PERRY |355-16-7439| EDITOR))
```

Now using `third` to access the third element of each sublist:

```
CL-USER 29 > (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                         (third x))
                     daily-planet)

(|123-76-4535| |089-52-6787| |951-26-1438| |355-16-7439|)
```

Now using `NTH` to access the third element of each sublist:

```
CL-USER 30 > (mapcar #'(lambda (x)
                         (nth 2 x))
                     daily-planet)

(|123-76-4535| |089-52-6787| |951-26-1438| |355-16-7439|)
```